# Can't access the body of HttpResponseMessage

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, httpresponse, httpcontent

I'm currently working on an API with .NET Core Web App for a test and I'm stuck on this.

Actually, I have this code:

```
namespace CoreWebApp.API.Admin
{
    [Route("api/country")]
    public class CountryController : Controller
    {
        // GET: api/country
        [HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage Get()
        {
            List<Country> countries = Shared.Database.SqlAction.CountriesTable.GetCountries();
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK) { Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(countries), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json") };
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is return an `HttpStatusCode` and an `HttpContent`. I then should get that on Postman:

```
[
    {
        "Name":"France"
    },
    {
        "Name":"Germany"
    },
    {
        "Name":"Spain"
    },
    ....
]
```

**StatusCode Ok 200**

---

However, I don't get this body at all, there is what I get:

```
{
    "version": {
        "major": 1,
        "minor": 1,
        "build": -1,
        "revision": -1,
        "majorRevision": -1,
        "minorRevision": -1
    },
    "content": {
        "headers": [
            {
                "key": "Content-Type",
                "value": [
                    "application/json; charset=utf-8"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "statusCode": 200,
    "reasonPhrase": "OK",
    "headers": [],
    "requestMessage": null,
    "isSuccessStatusCode": true
}
```

I'm searching for a while now and I'm still unable to get the data in the content, what am I doing wrong? It's my first .NET Core Api so feel free to give any advice if you have some :)

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Asp.net core does not support anymore the returning `HttpResponseMessage` type
to resolve your issue the recommended  return type is like the following

```
[HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GeTask()
        {
            List<Country> countries = Shared.Database.SqlAction.CountriesTable.GetCountries();
            return Ok(countries); 
}
```

**More** 
here how the ApiController in the full standard .net   looks like

```
//
        // Summary:
        //     Creates a System.Web.Http.Results.ResponseMessageResult with the specified response.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   response:
        //     The HTTP response message.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     A System.Web.Http.Results.ResponseMessageResult for the specified response.
        protected internal virtual ResponseMessageResult ResponseMessage(HttpResponseMessage response);
```

and the source code of controller base class  from .net core does not have any definition for `HttpResponseMessage`